# Magento - newsletter pop code using ajax update in form

Tags: ajax, forms, magento, newsletter

I have the below code that is being used in cms page pop up
the problem im having is if you leave email address input field blank and hit the submit (in the case "Get Code" button, you briefly see the red validation message but then hides the form, shows the hidden div.

why or how can I prevent this process, i want it to validate but proceed to show the hidden div content. Below is the code.

```
<div id="pop-confirm" style="display: none;">
<h1 style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">THANKS!</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h2>Use code: <strong>extra15</strong><br /> for 15% off your purchase.</h2>
</div>
<form id="newsletter-validate-detail" action="home/send" method="post" onSubmit="new Ajax.Updater({success:'newsletter-validate-detail'}, 'newsletter/subscriber/new', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:false, onComplete:function(request, json){Element.hide('newsletter-validate-detail');Element.show('pop-confirm');}, onLoading:function(request, json){}, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;">
<div class="block-content">
<h2>ENTER YOUR EMAIL<br /> AND GET</h2>
<div class="form-subscribe-header">
<h1>15% OFF</h1>
<br />
<h1>EVERYTHING!</h1>
</div>
<div class="input-box"><input id="newsletter" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="Sign up for our newsletter" type="text" name="email" /></div>
<br />
<div class="actions"><button class="button" title="Get Code" type="submit"><span><span>Get Code</span></span></button></div>
<br />
<p><em>* Promotion ends April 6th</em></p>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
        var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
// ]]></script>
```

Im very new to ajax so maybe ive done something wrong.

any ideas or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your onSubmit to the following:

```
onSubmit="if(newsletterSubscriberFormDetail.validator.validate()){ new Ajax.Updater({success:'newsletter-validate-detail'}, 'newsletter/subscriber/new', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:false, onComplete:function(request, json){Element.hide('newsletter-validate-detail');Element.show('pop-confirm');}, onLoading:function(request, json){}, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); } return false;"`
```

This wil trigger the validator before submitting the form with AJAX. Works perfect for me :)

Comment: Why not throw that into a function and call the function in the onSubmit?